# Get rid of "The requested resource [path] does not match convention mapped to '/Content'"

Tags: c#, node.js, nancy, self-hosting

I'm working with a self-hosted Nancy App, using it as an Api.

I published it on my server and now i'm working on a web-apps supposed to use this API.

The problem occurs when I'm requesting `GET http://myApi:[port]/api/token`.

When I test this using postman i get this :

- `StatusCode : 200`
- response Body contains the token i asked for

And when I'm using my web-app I get this in the nancy request-tracing :

- `StatusCode : 500`
- Log message :

  > [StaticContentConventionBuilder] The requested resource '/api/token' does not match convention mapped to '/Content'

So, if i understood what it means : On the 2nd request Nancy is trying to serve static Content and that's not what i want him to do since i just want to send back a json with my token.

I encountered a few topics where it's said that we can change the behaviour of the staticContentConventionsBuilder but most of it are just changing the static content folder.

I made sure that my request and response should have `Content-type : application/json` in header.

Postman request and web-apps request weren't made from the same machine but are part of the same networks and CORS are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that adding one line in the request's header works for me. 
Here is the line I added :
`Accept : "*/*;q=1"`

It's part of the header that postman send on every request.

You can find an explanation of this here :

[purpose of the Q value in Accept header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496570/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-q-values-in-the-http-accept-request-header)

or in the link provided in the answer.