# MVC 5 globalization culture

Tags: c#, datetime, web-config, asp.net-mvc-5, globalization

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application that is being deployed to `Azure`. I am wanting to setup browser based culture so that `DateTime` values are displayed in the correct format for different cultures.

Here is my `web.config` code:

```
<globalization culture="auto:en-US" uiCulture="auto:en-US" enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>
```

Is this all that needs to be done? When viewing a view after the website has been published to `Azure`, only IE displays the `DateTime` in my current OS format. Both Google Chrome and Firefox are not using my current OS format.

Why is the `DateTime` value not being displayed in my current culture format (en-NZ)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have removed the `enableClientBasedCulture="true"` from the `web.config` code, and the browser is still not displaying the `DateTime` values in my correct culture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation for the globalization Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.100).aspx) (.NET 4), the attribute does nothing at the current time.

> enableClientBasedCulture:
>
> Optional attribute. This attribute is not in use at this time.

Comment: How do you want them to display (dd/MM/yyyy)? And in a display format or in a textbox or in a datepicker?

Comment: The values are being displayed as simple text in a view.

Comment: If you set the culture to `<globalization culture="en-NZ" uiCulture="en-NZ" />` it will display as "dd/MM/yyyy". Or you can add the `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]` attribute to the property.

Comment: I do know how to manually set the culture. So are you saying that currently it is impossible to use the browser to determine the culture?

Comment: Impossible to get it reliably. You can read the browser language using `Request.UserLanguages` but browsers are not required to send the `Accept-Languages` header so it can be null, or it can return multiple items (refer [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552927/what-is-q-0-5-in-accept-http-headers)).

Comment: I have seen solutions where the user selects a language when they  register, so the value can be stored and retrieved for formatting purposes (e.g. in a custom `FormsAuthenticationTicket`).