# HTTP Content Negotiation with accept

Tags: http, http-headers, http-accept-header

Could someone help me clarify what the number values of the q parameter represent. I know that the values are used to select your preference but what I do not understand is how the numbers are used. For example in the below code would my preference remain the same if I were to use `application/json;q=0.3,*/*,q=0.2`?

```
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the server application.

Your first statement is saying "I will accept json if you can guarantee 30% quality, but if not I can accept anything at 20% quality".

Your second is saying "I will accept json if you can guarantee 90% quality, but if not I can accept anything at 80% quality".

However, the application *could* take that to mean "provide json if you can, otherwise anything else".

[Official spec here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

For more details [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8552927/413180).