# How to pass the default language to the Registration page?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

Is there a way to pass a specific UI language to the registration page? This is coming from the website and I want it to be the defaut option.

Comment: MPA or SPA project?

Comment: The solution differs on Angular and MVC

Comment: SPA, .net core + angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send the culture with these headers

```
c=...
uic=...
```

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Localization/AbpLocalizationHeaderRequestCultureProvider.cs#L12

and for MVC use culture parameter like below

```
/register?culture=tr
```

*must be the first parameter of the query string*

---

and last option; you can always override AbpUserRequestCultureProvider

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Localization/AbpUserRequestCultureProvider.cs

**UPDATE**:

According to the implementation it accepts query string parameters as culture like below

```
?culture=es-MX&ui-culture=es-MX
```

See https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2103

Comment: For the asp.net core / Angular version, can I sent it in the query string insteadf of the header? scince it is coming from an external website

Comment: updated my answer.. you can send query string parameters  see  https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2103

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the request headers sent by the browser, it includes "Accept-Language".  It can look something like this:

```
en-US,en;q=0.9,es-419;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
```

Generally, the preference runs in descending order, so here, the browser is saying it prefers U.S. english before anything else.  More here about what the q values mean:  [What is q=0.5 in Accept* HTTP headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552927/what-is-q-0-5-in-accept-http-headers?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

You can access this value through in the controller.

```
Request.Headers["Accept-Language"]
```